# Ubuntu 22.04 Thunderbolt dual display problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04, hdmi, thunderbolt

I have a problem regarding my new laptop and a thunderbolt USB-C dock. The laptop is a HP Elitebook 865 G9, the dock is a Hama 200100 10 port dock, with 2 HDMI and 1 DisplayPort (and diverse USB&Ethernet ports).

I use Ubuntu 22.04 as the operating system, with kernel 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The system has a AMD Ryzen 7 6850U CPU with integrated AMD graphics.

My problem is, that I cannot get two HDMI displays to work over the Hama USB-C docking station.
During boot I can see mirrored image on both displays, but after the system boots, one remains blank.
In the display settings however I can see both displays as active, also xrandr command shows both displays as connected, however on one display there is no HDMI signal. I tried google it, but unfortunatelly did not found any solution for this issue yet. Seems to be some AMDGPU related issue, however I found some patch regarding multiple USB-C video outputs, which should already be in the kernel as fix (checked the patch commits and the source code of the current kernel I'm running on).

Have no idea how to overcome this, would be nice to have both displays working.

xrandr output:

```
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     60.00 +  40.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-7 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-8 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-9 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output of lshw:

```
    product: HP EliteBook 865 16 inch G9 Notebook PC (473R9AV)
    vendor: HP
    serial: XYZ
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.4.0 dmi-3.4.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5336AN HP EliteBook frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=473R9AV uuid=123456789
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 8990
       vendor: HP
       physical id: 0
       version: KBC Version 09.3C.00
       serial: 123456789
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 0
          slot: L1 - Cache
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 1
          slot: L2 - Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 2
          slot: L3 - Cache
          size: 16MiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 6850U with Radeon Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 25.68.1
          serial: Unknown
          slot: FP7
          size: 1190MHz
          capacity: 4768MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: xxxx     
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: HP
          physical id: 10
          version: U82 Ver. 01.01.07
          date: 04/22/2022
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 32MiB
          capabilities: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 01
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: IOMMU
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 0.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi ht bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:32 ioport:6000(size=4096) memory:b4900000-b49fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 00
                serial: 123456789
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8852be driverversion=v1.15.6.0.2-0-gac110bf5.2021102 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
                resources: irq:105 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:b4900000-b49fffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:33 memory:b4800000-b48fffff           
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 3.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:34 ioport:4000(size=8192) memory:9c000000-b3ffffff ioport:8e0000000(size=671088640)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 4.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:35 ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:84000000-9bffffff ioport:8b0000000(size=671088640)
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:36 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:b4400000-b47fffff ioport:910000000(size=270532608)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Rembrandt
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: d4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
                resources: iomemory:90-8f iomemory:90-8f irq:60 memory:910000000-91fffffff memory:920000000-9201fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:b4700000-b477ffff
           *-multimedia:0
                description: Audio device
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.1
                logical name: card0
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:106 memory:b47c8000-b47cbfff
              *-input:0
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input14
                   logical name: /dev/input/event10
              *-input:1
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7
                   physical id: 1
                   logical name: input15
                   logical name: /dev/input/event11
              *-input:2
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=8
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: input16
                   logical name: /dev/input/event12
              *-input:3
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=9
                   physical id: 3
                   logical name: input17
                   logical name: /dev/input/event13
           *-generic
                description: Encryption controller
                product: VanGogh PSP/CCP
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ccp latency=0
                resources: irq:24 memory:b4600000-b46fffff memory:b47cc000-b47cdfff
           *-usb:0
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.3
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:56 memory:b4400000-b44fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@1
                   logical name: usb1
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Bluetooth Radio
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@1:3
                      version: 0.00
                      serial: 00e04c000001
                      capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
                      description: Generic USB device
                      vendor: Synaptics, Inc.
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:4
                      version: 0.00
                      serial: a466ef813ca5
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2
                   logical name: usb2
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-usb:1
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.4
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:61 memory:b4500000-b45fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-multimedia:1
                description: Multimedia controller
                product: Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.5
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.5
                version: 60
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_pci_acp6x latency=0
                resources: irq:103 memory:b4780000-b47bffff
           *-multimedia:2
                description: Audio device
                product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.6
                bus info: pci@0000:63:00.6
                logical name: card1
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:107 memory:b47c0000-b47c7fff
              *-input:0
                   product: HD-Audio Generic Mic
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input18
                   logical name: /dev/input/event14
              *-input:1
                   product: HD-Audio Generic Headphone
                   physical id: 1
                   logical name: input19
                   logical name: /dev/input/event15
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.3
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:37 memory:b4000000-b43fffff
           *-usb:0
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:64:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:62 memory:b4000000-b40fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@5
                   logical name: usb5
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Video
                      product: HP 5MP Camera: HP IR Camera
                      vendor: DLTDC0A9IGH5V4
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@5:1
                      logical name: input24
                      logical name: /dev/input/event19
                      logical name: input25
                      logical name: /dev/input/event21
                      version: 0.05
                      serial: 01.00.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@6
                   logical name: usb6
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usb:1
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:64:00.3
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:83 memory:b4100000-b41fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@9
                   logical name: usb9
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@10
                   logical name: usb10
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-usb:2
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:64:00.4
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:64 memory:b4200000-b42fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@7
                   logical name: usb7
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: USB hub
                      product: USB2.0 Hub
                      vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@7:1
                      version: 3.a4
                      capabilities: usb-2.10
                      configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usb:0
                         description: USB hub
                         product: USB 2.0 Hub
                         vendor: Terminus Technology Inc.
                         physical id: 2
                         bus info: usb@7:1.2
                         version: 1.11
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                       *-usb:0
                            description: Mouse
                            product: SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse
                            vendor: SIGMACHIP
                            physical id: 2
                            bus info: usb@7:1.2.2
                            logical name: input20
                            logical name: /dev/input/event16
                            logical name: /dev/input/mouse2
                            version: 1.10
                            capabilities: usb-1.10 usb
                            configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
                       *-usb:1
                            description: Keyboard
                            product: SEM HCT Keyboard System Control
                            vendor: SEM
                            physical id: 3
                            bus info: usb@7:1.2.3
                            logical name: input21
                            logical name: /dev/input/event17
                            logical name: input21::capslock
                            logical name: input21::numlock
                            logical name: input21::scrolllock
                            logical name: input22
                            logical name: /dev/input/event18
                            logical name: input23
                            logical name: /dev/input/event20
                            version: 1.10
                            capabilities: usb-1.10 usb
                            configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=1Mbit/s
                       *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                            description: Generic USB device
                            product: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
                            vendor: VIA Technologies Inc.
                            physical id: 4
                            bus info: usb@7:1.2.4
                            version: 7.01
                            serial: 0000000000000001
                            capabilities: usb-2.01
                            configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
                         description: Generic USB device
                         product: USB Billboard Device
                         vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                         physical id: 5
                         bus info: usb@7:1.5
                         version: 0.01
                         serial: 0000000000000001
                         capabilities: usb-2.01
                         configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@8
                   logical name: usb8
                   version: 5.15
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=10000Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: USB hub
                      product: USB3.0 Hub
                      vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@8:1
                      version: 3.a4
                      capabilities: usb-3.10
                      configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
                    *-usb
                         description: Generic USB device
                         product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
                         vendor: Realtek
                         physical id: 4
                         bus info: usb@8:1.4
                         version: 31.00
                         serial: 001000001
                         capabilities: usb-3.00
                         configuration: driver=r8152 maxpower=288mA speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usb:3
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.5
                bus info: pci@0000:64:00.5
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix usb4_host_interface bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
                resources: irq:38 memory:b4300000-b437ffff
           *-usb:4
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.6
                bus info: pci@0000:64:00.6
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix usb4_host_interface bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
                resources: irq:65 memory:b4380000-b43fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: c
       bus info: usb@8:1.4
       logical name: enx00e04ce0154b
       serial: 00:e0:4c:e0:15:4b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.12 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 ip=172.16.1.252 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling around, investigating a lot (did BIOS update, tried diverse BIOS settings, etc.), I tried to install the most recent kernel (5.19.5-051905-generic) using the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel installer, and it did the trick. Seems either my motherboard/GPU/CPU is too new for the 5.15 kernel, or there has been done some bug fixing regarding Thunderbolt dock/multiple HDMI outputs, either way now both displays are working without any problem.

Comment: How did you get 5.19.5-051905-generic version? My mainline --list shows only 5.15 kernels.

Comment: @BeerBrother I installed with the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer. The newest you can install is 6.0.6. The dual display was working with 5.19.5 (I did not try any older, this was the newest at that time) and was working with 6.0.3 also.